# Make linked or appended objects part of another blend file no strings attached. (Blender 2.82)

Tags: import, linked-data, append

I have linked a separate blend file of a **Claw** for my character but can't join and edit it, I just need it to be unlinked and be part of the character blend file.

Comment: If you just want to edit it, you could use library overrides. If you want to make it completely local, then you could use F3 > *Make Local* on all linked parts. Appended object are already a local copy, it shouldn't require any additional steps.

Comment: Thanks for the time Robert! But I still can't edit the object, pressing TAB doesn't do anything and the materials tab is missing, I also cant drop material into it. Blender still recognizes it as an outside object. my main goal is to convert linked/appended objects and attached it to my character like kitbashing.

Comment: Have you done this for all parts of the object (object data, materials etc.)? Open the outliner select the object and make everything underneath the object in the hierarchy local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer somewhere on the internet, just press **CTRL + A -> Make Instances Real** and boom! I can finally sleep.

Comment: This only works if you're creating instanced collections (*Add > Collection Instance* or *File > Link* and selecting a collection) or if you're instancing objects (*Object Properties > Instancing* and parenting objects to it). For more information take a look at the [*Instancing*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html) chapter in the manual. If you're simply linking an object, this will not create a local copy.

Comment: It works on the linked objects of my character like a charm but thanks for taking your time answering my question, appreciated.